# Unable to set state in the component

Tags: reactjs

When the click event takes place, the state is not set to the value given inside the CompOne. It still show the initial state and console logs the old state which is "hello".

```
var CompOne = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      edit: "hello"
    } 
  },

  editme: function () {
   this.setState({
     edit: "there"
   })
   console.log(this.state.edit)  
 },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.name}
        <button onClick={this.editme}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})


var Pri = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        < CompOne name = "Anne"/>
        < CompOne name = "Bob"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render( <Pri /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `setState` is not synchronous. Here is a note about this from [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate);

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls
>   may be batched for performance gains.

In human terms this means that if you call `setState` and try to read the state immediately, the state could be changed or it could be the same.

The solution that you can use is to pass a callback to `setState` method as a second parameter:

```
editme: function () {
   this.setState({
     edit: "there"
   }, function(){
       // this function would be invoked only when the state is changed
       console.log(this.state.edit);
   });
}
```

The purpose of the second parameter is described in the same documentation article:

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once `setState` is completed and the component is
>   re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the callback function in `setState` because setState takes time to mutate and you `console.log` gets executed before the state is mutated as statements are executed asynchronously.

```
   editme: function () {
       this.setState({
         edit: "there"
       }, function(){

       console.log(this.state.edit) 
       }) 
     },
```

```js
    var CompOne = React.createClass({
    
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          edit: "hello"
        } 
      },
    
      editme: function () {
       this.setState({
         edit: "there"
       }, function(){
         
       console.log(this.state.edit) 
       }) 
     },
    
      render: function(){
        return (
          <div>
            {this.props.name}
            <button onClick={this.editme}>Edit</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
    
    
    var Pri = React.createClass({
      render: function () {
        return (
          <div>
            < CompOne name = "Anne"/>
            < CompOne name = "Bob"/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    })
    
    ReactDOM.render( <Pri /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```